# How do you store an array into a variable?

Tags: c

If I have an array of 4 values, how would I store all the values into one variable?

```
    char d[4];
    int allvalues;
    d[0] = 1;
    d[1] = 2;
    d[2] = 3;
    d[3] = 4;
```

I want **allvalues = 1234**. If I add this piece of code, the output comes out different.

```
  allvalues = d;
  printf("%d", allvalues);
```

Thank you!

Comment: `allvalues = 1000*d[0] + 100*d[1] + 10*d[2] + d[3];`

Comment: Never mind I think its working.

Comment: That's because you have used the wrong indices when filling `d`. You used 3 and 4 instead of 2 and 3, using `d[4]` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yea my bad I typed the code in a rush. I asked a basic question no wonder why I have 5 thumbs down.

Comment: @Ammar You `really` need to work on your C basics Amar.How can you even imagine a **sin** ,a **taboo** like `allvalues=d` where `allvalues` is an integer variable and `d` is a character array object?It's more outrageous than saying Kim Kardashian has a slim waist....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allvalues = d[3] + 10 * ( d[2] + 10 * ( d[1] + 10 * d[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through the array and append the values to a string. Something like this should do the trick:

```
char d[4];
string allvalues;
d[0] = 1;
d[1] = 2;
d[3] = 3;
d[4] = 4;

for(int i =0; i<4; i++)
{
  allvalues = allvalues+d[i]
}
 printf("%s", allvalues);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

The following will convert a char array to an integer.

```
allvalues = atoi(d)
```

Comment: Needs a 0-terminated array, and has no error checking. Once you have a 0-terminated array, I'd rather use `strtol`.

Comment: `atoi()` does no error checking.

Comment: @DanielFischer isn't strtol() in C++. This is marked as C. But I agree I forgot about the null terminating.

Comment: @Evo510 No, it's a C function (that is also available in C++).